# How to install and use GAS (GNU Compiler) on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, assembly, gnu-assembler

I'm using Ubuntu, and I was looking for an assembler compiler for Linux, and I found GAS.

I'm trying to install it and run it, but I can't.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`as` is the [GNU Assembler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler). It's found in `binutils` but if you do:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

You will get `gas` along with `gcc` (which default uses `gas` for assembling on the back end).

For a 'tutorial' about using `gas`, you probably want to read [Programming From the Ground Up](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/pgubook/), which uses it.

---

To build a static executable from a `.s` file,

```
#!/bin/bash
f="${1:-}"
as "${f}" -o "${f%%.s}.o" && ld "${f%%.s}.0" -o "${f%%.s}"
gcc -nostdlib -static "${f}" -o "${f%%.s}"
```

If you want to link with libraries, it's normally easiest to let gcc use the right command line options for `as` and `ld` when building an executable from an asm source file.
`gcc foo.s -o foo` will work if your `foo.s` defines a `main` function.

Also related: [Assembling 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit system (GNU toolchain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain) if you're writing 32-bit programs on an x86-64 system.

Comment: I've installed, and now to compile a .asm file? Do I have to paste the file in the same folder of the compiler?? –

Comment: @phyhclo: If you installed with `apt-get` or similar tools, it should be already in your system PATH.  So simply try `as` or `gas` on the terminal and see what it says.  If `as` was not installed and you typed out `as` on the terminal, Ubuntu systems normally show the package in which the command is bundled.  So you can simply go ahead and `sudo apt-get install <missing package name>` on the terminal.

Answer (score 5):

It's in the `binutils` package.

Comment: yeah, I downloaded a folder with a lot of folders inside. one of them is binutils. But What file in binutils folder I access, and how?

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Fire up Synaptic and enter "gnu assembler" into the quick search bar. It's immediately obvious that `binutils` is the required package.

And you may well find it's already installed. My `binutils 2.20.1-3ubuntu7` is already installed and I have a fairly vanilla set-up.

Entering `as --version` from a terminal window will let you know:

```
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.20.1-system.20100303
Copyright 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or later.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
This assembler was configured for a target of `i486-linux-gnu'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO.html? on Debian GAS is contained in the package

> binutils

so

```
sudo apt-get install binutils
dpkg -L binutils
```

$man as

Comment: I've installed, and now to compile a .asm file? Do I have to paste the file in the same folder of the compiler??

Comment: @psyhclo sounds like you need a tutorial? http://www.hep.wisc.edu/~pinghc/x86AssmTutorial.htm

Answer (score 0):

**Build from source and use it**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eux

# Build.
sudo apt-get build-dep binutils
git clone git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git
cd binutils-gdb
git checkout binutils-2_31
./configure --target x86_64-elf --prefix "$(pwd)/install"
make -j `nproc`
make install

# Test it out.
cat <<'EOF' > hello.S
.data
    s:
        .ascii "hello world\n"
        len = . - s
.text
    .global _start
    _start:
        mov $4, %eax
        mov $1, %ebx
        mov $s, %ecx
        mov $len, %edx
        int $0x80
        mov $1, %eax
        mov $0, %ebx
        int $0x80
EOF
./install/bin/x86_64-elf-as -o hello.o hello.S
./install/bin/x86_64-elf-ld -o hello hello.o
./hello
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-cheat/blob/8b450549cf2482028bf43c94b267fa55d89ea4e6/binutils.sh).

TODO: how to configure `as` specific options? We have used the `./configure` from the `binutils-gdb` top-level, but that contains options from multiple projects such as `gdb` I believe, and not `as` specific ones?

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.