# Assembling 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit system (GNU toolchain)

Tags: linux, assembly, build, x86, att

I wrote assembly code that successfully compiles:

```
as power.s -o power.o
```

However, it fails when I try to link the object file:

```
ld power.o -o power
```

In order to run on the 64 bit OS (Ubuntu 14.04), I added `.code32` at the beginning of the `power.s` file, however I still get the error:

**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

`power.s`:

```
.code32
.section .data
.section .text
.global _start
_start:
pushl $3
pushl $2 
call power 
addl $8, %esp
pushl %eax 

pushl $2
pushl $5
call power
addl $8, %esp

popl %ebx
addl %eax, %ebx

movl $1, %eax
int $0x80



.type power, @function
power:
pushl %ebp  
movl %esp, %ebp 
subl $4, %esp 
movl 8(%ebp), %ebx 
movl 12(%ebp), %ecx 
movl %ebx, -4(%ebp) 

power_loop_start:
cmpl $1, %ecx 
je end_power
movl -4(%ebp), %eax
imull %ebx, %eax
movl %eax, -4(%ebp)

decl %ecx
jmp power_loop_start

end_power:
movl -4(%ebp), %eax 
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

Comment: What have you done to solve this already? Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to see where it crashes? Do you know what a segmentation fault is? (It has nothing to do with running 32 bit code on a 64 bit system).

Comment: `.code32` doesn't set the object file format.  The assembler will make 32bit code, but put it into a file that defaults to running as 64bit code.  David has pointed out a separate problem, but it will still crash after fixing that.  (Or at least get wrong answers.  `objdump -d power` to disassemble the instructions the way your CPU will interpret them.)  Use `gcc -m32 -static -nostartfiles power.S -o power`.

Comment: @PeterCordes : I agree the big issue with segfaulting will be 32-bit code running as 64-bit program, but I don't believe that David's analysis is correct (I don't believe there is a stack issue with the `ret` that would cause a segfault). the result of 2^3 + 5^2 should be 33 (which it appears to be)

Comment: Looking again, you're right @MichaelPetch. I mistook the %ebp references at first glance this morning.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer : Not a problem David, been there done that!

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. This problem is due to the "32-bit code running as 64-bit program" just like  PeterCordes MichaelPetch said. I followed PeterCorde's `gcc -m32 -static -nostartfiles power.S -o power` Then I can successfully run the power. The `-m32` option  allows 32-bit code to be generated  on the x86-64 platform. However, I don't know why I should use `-static` option to statically link programs. And I didn't find the `-nostartfiles` option's meaning. @PeterCordes

Comment: `-static -nostartfiles` replicates the behaviour of `ld power.o -o power`, but with the right `-m` option to make 32bit ELF executables.  See [the docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html), or the gcc man page...  Or build without those options, and use `file` and `objdump -d` to see the difference.

Answer (score 23):

**TL:DR: use `gcc -m32 -static -nostdlib foo.S`** (or equivalent as and ld options).
Or if you don't define your own `_start`, just `gcc -m32 -no-pie foo.S`

**You may need to install `gcc-multilib` if you link libc**, or however your distro packages `/usr/lib32/libc.so`, `/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so` and so on.  But if you define your own `_start` and don't link libraries, you don't need the library package, just a **kernel that supports 32-bit processes and system calls**.  This includes most distros, but not Windows Subsystem for Linux v1.

#### Don't use `.code32`

`.code32` does *not* change the output file format, and that's what determines the mode your program will run in.  It's up to you to not try to run 32bit code in 64bit mode.  `.code32` is for assembling kernels that have some 16 and some 32-bit code, and stuff like that.  If that's not what you're doing, avoid it so you'll get build-time errors when you build a `.S` in the wrong mode if it has any `push` or `pop` instructions, for example.  `.code32` just lets you create confusing-to-debug runtime problems instead of build-time errors.

Suggestion: use the `.S` extension for hand-written assembler.  (`gcc -c foo.S` will run it through the C preprocessor before `as`, so you can `#include <sys/syscall.h>` for syscall numbers, for example).  Also, it distinguishes it from `.s` compiler output (from `gcc foo.c -O3 -S`).

### To build 32-bit binaries, use one of these commands

```bash
gcc -g foo.S -o foo -m32 -nostdlib -static  # static binary with absolutely no libraries or startup code
                       # -nostdlib still dynamically links when Linux where PIE is the default, or on OS X

gcc -g foo.S -o foo -m32 -no-pie            # dynamic binary including the startup boilerplate code.
     # Use with code that defines a main(), not a _start
```

[Documentation for `nostdlib`, `-nostartfiles`, and `-static`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).

---

#### Using libc functions from `_start` (see the end of this answer for an example)

Some functions, like `malloc(3)`, or stdio functions including `printf(3)`, depend on some global data being initialized (e.g. `FILE *stdout` and the object it actually points to).

`gcc -nostartfiles` leaves out the CRT `_start` boilerplate code, but still links `libc` (dynamically, by default).  On Linux, shared libraries can have initializer sections that are run by the dynamic linker when it loads them, before jumping to your `_start` entry point.  **So `gcc -nostartfiles hello.S` still lets you call `printf`**.  For a dynamic executable, the kernel runs `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` on it instead of running it directly (use `readelf -a` to see the "ELF interpreter" string in your binary).  When your `_start` eventually runs, not all the registers will be zeroed, because the dynamic linker ran code in your process.

However, **`gcc -nostartfiles -static hello.S` will link, but crash at runtime** if you call `printf` or something without calling glibc's internal init functions.  (see Michael Petch's comment).

---

Of course you can put any combination of `.c`, `.S`, and `.o` files on the  same command line to link them all into one executable.  If you have any C, don't forget `-Og -Wall -Wextra`: you don't want to be debugging your asm when the problem was something simple in the C that calls it that the compiler could have warned you about.

Use `-v` to have gcc show you the commands it runs to assemble and link.  **To do it "manually"**:

```bash
as foo.S -o foo.o -g --32 &&      # skips the preprocessor
ld -o foo foo.o  -m elf_i386

file foo
foo: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```

`gcc -nostdlib -m32` is easier to remember and type than the two different options for as and ld (`--32` and `-m elf_i386`).  Also, it works on all platforms, including ones where executable format isn't ELF.  (**But Linux examples won't work on OS X, because the system call numbers are different**, or on Windows because it doesn't even use the `int 0x80` ABI.)

---

#### NASM/YASM

gcc can't handle NASM syntax.  (`-masm=intel` is more like MASM than NASM syntax, where you need `offset symbol` to get the address as an immediate).  And of course the directives are different (e.g. `.globl` vs `global`).

You can build with [`nasm`](http://www.nasm.us/) or [`yasm`](http://yasm.tortall.net/), then link the `.o` with `gcc` as above, or `ld` directly.

I use a wrapper script to avoid the repetitive typing of the same filename with three different extensions.  (nasm and yasm default to `file.asm` -> `file.o`, unlike GNU as's default output of `a.out`).  Use this with `-m32` to assemble and link 32bit ELF executables.  Not all OSes use ELF, so this script is less portable than using `gcc -nostdlib -m32` to link would be..

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# usage: asm-link [-q] [-m32] foo.asm  [assembler options ...]
# Just use a Makefile for anything non-trivial.  This script is intentionally minimal and doesn't handle multiple source files
# Copyright 2020 Peter Cordes.  Public domain.  If it breaks, you get to keep both pieces

verbose=1                       # defaults
fmt=-felf64
#ldopt=-melf_i386
ldlib=()

linker=ld
#dld=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
while getopts 'Gdsphl:m:nvqzN' opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        m)  if [ "m$OPTARG" = "m32" ]; then
                fmt=-felf32
                ldopt=-melf_i386
                #dld=/lib/ld-linux.so.2  # FIXME: handle linker=gcc non-static executable
            fi
            if [ "m$OPTARG" = "mx32" ]; then
                fmt=-felfx32
                ldopt=-melf32_x86_64
            fi
            ;;
        #   -static
        l)  linker="gcc -no-pie -fno-plt -nostartfiles"; ldlib+=("-l$OPTARG");;
        p)  linker="gcc -pie -fno-plt -nostartfiles"; ldlib+=("-pie");;
        h)  ldlib+=("-Ttext=0x200800000");;   # symbol addresses outside the low 32.  data and bss go in range of text
                          # strace -e raw=write  will show the numeric address
        G)  nodebug=1;;      # .label: doesn't break up objdump output
        d)  disas=1;;
        s)  runsize=1;;
        n)  use_nasm=1 ;;
        q)  verbose=0 ;;
        v)  verbose=1 ;;
        z)  ldlib+=("-zexecstack") ;;
        N)  ldlib+=("-N") ;;   # --omagic = read+write text section
    esac
done
shift "$((OPTIND-1))"   # Shift off the options and optional --

src=$1
base=${src%.*}
shift

#if [[ ${#ldlib[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
    #    ldlib+=("--dynamic-linker" "$dld")
    #ldlib=("-static" "${ldlib[@]}")
#fi

set -e
if (($use_nasm)); then
  #  (($nodebug)) || dbg="-g -Fdwarf"     # breaks objdump disassembly, and .labels are included anyway
    ( (($verbose)) && set -x    # print commands as they're run, like make
    nasm "$fmt" -Worphan-labels $dbg  "$src" "$@" &&
        $linker $ldopt -o "$base" "$base.o"  "${ldlib[@]}")
else
    (($nodebug)) || dbg="-gdwarf2"
    ( (($verbose)) && set -x    # print commands as they're run, like make
    yasm "$fmt" -Worphan-labels $dbg "$src" "$@" &&
        $linker $ldopt -o "$base" "$base.o"  "${ldlib[@]}" )
fi

# yasm -gdwarf2 includes even .local labels so they show up in objdump output
# nasm defaults to that behaviour of including even .local labels

# nasm defaults to STABS debugging format, but -g is not the default

if (($disas));then
    objdump -drwC -Mintel "$base"
fi

if (($runsize));then
    size $base
fi
```

I prefer YASM for a few reasons, including that it defaults to making long-`nop`s instead of padding with many single-byte `nop`s.  That makes for messy disassembly output, as well as being slower if the nops ever run.  (In NASM, you have to use the `smartalign` macro package.)

However, YASM hasn't been maintained for a while and only NASM has AVX512 support; these days I more often just use NASM.

---

#### Example: a program using libc functions from _start

```asm
# hello32.S

#include <asm/unistd_32.h>   // syscall numbers.  only #defines, no C declarations left after CPP to cause asm syntax errors

.text
#.global main   # uncomment these to let this code work as _start, or as main called by glibc _start
#main:
#.weak _start

.global _start
_start:
        mov     $__NR_gettimeofday, %eax  # make a syscall that we can see in strace output so we know when we get here
        int     $0x80

        push    %esp
        push    $print_fmt
        call   printf

        #xor    %ebx,%ebx                 # _exit(0)
        #mov    $__NR_exit_group, %eax    # same as glibc's _exit(2) wrapper
        #int    $0x80                     # won't flush the stdio buffer

        movl    $0, (%esp)   # reuse the stack slots we set up for printf, instead of popping
        call    exit         # exit(3) does an fflush and other cleanup

        #add    $8, %esp     # pop the space reserved by the two pushes
        #ret                 # only works in main, not _start

.section .rodata
print_fmt: .asciz "Hello, World!\n%%esp at startup = %#lx\n"
```

---

```bash
$ gcc -m32 -nostdlib hello32.S
/tmp/ccHNGx24.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `printf'
...
$ gcc -m32 hello32.S
/tmp/ccQ4SOR8.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
...
```

---

Fails at run-time, because nothing calls the glibc init functions.  (`__libc_init_first`, `__dl_tls_setup`, and `__libc_csu_init` in that order, according to Michael Petch's comment.  Other `libc` implementations exist, including [MUSL](https://www.musl-libc.org/) which is designed for static linking and works without initialization calls.)

```bash
$ gcc -m32 -nostartfiles -static hello32.S     # fails at run-time
$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, BuildID[sha1]=ef4b74b1c29618d89ad60dbc6f9517d7cdec3236, not stripped
$ strace -s128 ./a.out
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], [/* 70 vars */]) = 0
[ Process PID=29681 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
gettimeofday(NULL, NULL)                = 0
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_addr=0} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

You could also `gdb ./a.out`, and run `b _start`, `layout reg`, `run`, and see what happens.

---

```bash
$ gcc -m32 -nostartfiles hello32.S             # Correct command line
$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=7b0a731f9b24a77bee41c13ec562ba2a459d91c7, not stripped

$ ./a.out
Hello, World!
%esp at startup = 0xffdf7460

$ ltrace -s128 ./a.out > /dev/null
printf("Hello, World!\n%%esp at startup = %#lx\n", 0xff937510)      = 43    # note the different address: Address-space layout randomization at work
exit(0 <no return ...>
+++ exited (status 0) +++

$ strace -s128 ./a.out > /dev/null        # redirect stdout so we don't see a mix of normal output and trace output
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], [/* 70 vars */]) = 0
[ Process PID=29729 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
brk(0)                                  = 0x834e000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
....   more syscalls from dynamic linker code
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
mmap2(NULL, 1814236, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xfffffffff7556000    # map the executable text section of the library
... more stuff
# end of dynamic linker's code, finally jumps to our _start

gettimeofday({1461874556, 431117}, NULL) = 0
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(1, 3), ...}) = 0  # stdio is figuring out whether stdout is a terminal or not
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, 0xff938870) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfffffffff7743000      # 4k buffer for stdout
write(1, "Hello, World!\n%esp at startup = 0xff938fb0\n", 43) = 43
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

If we'd used `_exit(0)`, or made the `sys_exit` system call ourselves with `int 0x80`, [the `write(2)` wouldn't have happened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36632644/gnu-as-puts-works-but-printf-does-not/36633225#36633225).  With stdout redirected to a non-tty, it defaults to full-buffered (not line-buffered), so the `write(2)` is only triggered by the `fflush(3)` as part of `exit(3)`.  Without redirection, calling `printf(3)` with a string containing newlines will flush immediately.

Behaving differently depending on whether stdout is a terminal can be desirable, but only if you do it on purpose, not by mistake.

Comment: When building with `-nostartfiles -static` it can be dangerous in many environments if the _C_ runtime needs to be run ahead of time. For simple things you'll probably not have a problem, but even printf can become a problem. That is why if you intend to use `glibc` statically, your code should call  `__libc_init_first`,  `__dl_tls_setup`, `__libc_csu_init` to be called manually (in that order) at program startup. You can avoid this by using _C_ libraries like [MUSL](https://www.musl-libc.org/) which require no initialization before functions are called. They are designed for static linking

Comment: You can get away with dynamic linking of _GLIBC_ because that shared object will have its initialization code called automatically by the dynamic linker which will do those initialization calls.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I did mention that in the comment above that line, if you scroll to the right...  I didn't want to clutter the answer, but maybe that should be more prominent.  Oh right, maybe my comment is wrong, because it only works with *dynamic* linking and `-nostartfiles`.  Anyway, gtg, bbl in a couple hours.

Comment: Edit if you have any nice ideas for how to present that info, otherwise I will at some point.

Comment: Take care. Coincidentally I discovered we shared an answer related to this previously http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208824/number-of-executed-instructions-different-for-hello-world-program-nasm-assembly . I had forgotten about it, although it was in the context of reducing code size so I never mentioned the initialization sequence needed for static linking to work.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Is this too much stuff in one answer?  I think I kept the essential info up front before wandering off into big examples and stuff.  The x86 tag wiki links this answer for building 32bit code on a 64bit machine, so I figured that sending a newbie to this question might clear up other confusions, too, as well as illustrate strace and ltrace, and at least mention gdb.

Answer (score 7):

I'm learning x86 assembly (on 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04) and had a similar problem *with the exact same example* (it's from **Programming From the Ground Up**, in chapter 4 [http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pgubook/ ]).

After poking around I found the following two lines assembled and linked this:

```
as power.s -o power.o --32  
ld power.o -o power -m elf_i386
```

These tell the computer that you're only working in 32-bit (despite the 64-bit architecture).

If you want to use `gdb debugging`, then use the assembler line:

```
as --gstabs power.s -o power.o --32.
```

The .code32 seems to be unnecessary.

I haven't tried it your way, but the gnu assembler (gas) also seems okay with:
.globl start
  # (that is, no 'a' in global).

Moreover, I'd suggest you probably want to keep the comments from the original code as it seems to be recommended to comment profusely in assembly. (Even if you are the only one to look at the code, it'll make it easier to figure out what you were doing if you look at it months or years later.)

It would be nice to know how to alter this to use the `64-bit R*X` and `RBP`, `RSP` registers though.

Comment: Correct, `.code32` is useless here, as I explained in my answer.  And yes, [`.globl` is the normal GAS directive.  `.global` is an alias for it](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Global.html).