# Linking assembly .s with gcc errors

Tags: gcc, assembly

Hi i am getting several errors while linking my ".s" file together.

- First of all, i compile the file via **"gcc -S -m32 search.c"** to
  get my 32-bit assembler code.
- Secondly i want to link the program back together by using **"gcc -o

  search search.s"**

If i do this i get the following error: "*Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push."* I tried to use google to solve the problem and found a solution by using the --32 option flag. But this did not work either. The following error shows up as an result:
*usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output*. The third option by adding .code32 to the .s file, gcc let me compile it. Though by executing the console immediately says "core dumped".

So i really do not know what to do now. Anyone has an idea how i get things working?

Cheers

Comment: You should use `-m32` for linking too.

Comment: Haha it was so easy. Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assembling 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit system (GNU toolchain)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assemble with `--32`, and link with `-m32`.

**gcc -m32 -o search search.s**

Without `-m32`, the output is going to be a 64-bit executable. The error message is due to the input object being a 32-bit object; you can't produce a 64-bit executable from 32-bit objects.