# junk `(0,1,1)' after expression

Tags: gcc, assembly, gnu-assembler

When I try and assemble the program, I get a bunch of the following error messages:

```
misha@hp-laptop:~/test$ as -gstabs test.s -o test.o && ld test.o -o a.out && rm test.o && ./a.out
test.s: Assembler messages:
test.s:19: Error: junk `(0,0,1)' after expression
test.s:20: Error: junk `(0,1,1)' after expression
test.s:21: Error: junk `(0,2,1)' after expression
test.s:22: Error: junk `(0,3,1)' after expression
```

Can anybody please tell me what exactly I'm doing wrong that my program won't run? Obviously, it's something that has to do with the way I'm trying to get access to the array elements each of which is one byte long. Here's the program itself:

```
/******************************************************************************
 *                                                                            *
 * This program prints the string "foo" on the console.                       *
 *                                                                            *
 ******************************************************************************/

.section .data
    array: .byte 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00  # An array of four bytes
    size:  .int  4                       # The size of the array


.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    movb   $0x66, %ah   # 66 is the hexadecimal value for 'f'
    movb   $0x6F, %al   # 6F is the hexadecimal value for 'o'
    movb   $0x6F, %bh   # 6F is the hexadecimal value for 'o'
    movb   $0x0A, %bl   # A is the hexadecimal value for '\n'
    movb   %ah, array(0, 0, 1)
    movb   %al, array(0, 1, 1)
    movb   %bh, array(0, 2, 1)
    movb   %bl, array(0, 3, 1)

    # print
    movl   $4, %eax       # 4 is the number for the write system call
    movl   $1, %ebx       # The file descriptor to write to (1 - STDOUT)
    movl   $array, %ecx   # The starting address of the string to print
    movl   size, %edx     # The number of bytes to print
    int    $0x80          # Wake up the kernel to run the write system call

    # exit
    movl   $1, %eax       # 1 is the number for the exit system call
    movl   $0, %ebx       # Exit status code (echo $?)
    int    $0x80          # Wake up the kernel to run the exit system call

/*

Compile and run:

as -gstabs test.s -o test.o && \
ld test.o -o a.out && \
rm test.o && \
./a.out

*/
```

Comment: I'd suggest keeping your hand-written asm source in a `.S`, not a `.s`.  `gcc -S test.c` will clobber `test.s` without asking, but nothing ever uses `.S` as an output file extension by default.  All of glibc's asm source files are `.S`, for example.  You can also easily compile with `gcc -m32 -nostdlib test.S`.

Comment: Your laptop is hopefully not running 32bit Linux, so you will need `-m32` to run 32bit code.  This code might actually happen to work in 64bit mode, since the `int 0x80` ABI is still available, but as soon as you modify `%esp` instead of `%rsp`, you're screwed.  See [this answer re: building 32bit code on a 64bit system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain/36901649#36901649), and other links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no asm syntax for multi-dimensional arrays, unless you build it yourself with macros.  Or maybe you come up with that by replacing unused registers with `0` in `(base, index, scale)` syntax.

What you can do is use an [expression](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Integer-Exprs.html) involving a [label](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbols.html) to get offsets from it, like `movb  $constant, array + 4`.

Looking at compiler output is often a good way to learn how to do things in asm, from syntax basics to clever optimization tricks.  On the [Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g6,options:'-O3+-Wall+-Wextra+-fverbose-asm++-m32',source:'%23include+%3Cstring.h%3E%0Achar+arr%5B100%5D%3B%0Avoid+copy_string()%7B+memcpy(%26arr%5B4%5D,+%22foo%5Cn%22,+4)%3B+%7D%0A%0A//+gcc+has+had+this+optimizer+failure+to+merge+stores+as+a+regression+from+before+gcc4%0A//+clang+optimizes+this+the+same,+though.%0Avoid+store_bytes()%7B+arr%5B0%5D+%3D+!'f!'%3B+arr%5B1%5D+%3D+!'o!'%3B+arr%5B2%5D+%3D+!'o!'%3B+arr%5B3%5D+%3D+!'%5Cn!'%3B+%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3):

```
#include <string.h>
char arr[100];   // uninitialized global array
void copy_string(){ memcpy(&arr[4], "foo\n", 4); }

    // -O3 -fverbose-asm output:
    movl    $175075174, arr+4       #, MEM[(void *)&arr + 4B]
    ret

    .bss
    .align 32
arr:
    .zero   100
```

**So, `arr+4` is the syntax.**  We could write `movl $const, arr+4(%eax)` to do something like the C expression `array[4 + i]`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes) for a complete list of x86 addressing modes (mostly NASM / MASM syntax, but what really matters is what's encodable in machine code.)  See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

---

Also notice how gcc [puts uninitialized arrays in the `.bss`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/bss.html#bss) (rather than `.data` or `.rodata`).  That means there aren't a bunch of zero-bytes in your executable.   Instead of switching to the section with `.bss`, you could also use `.comm array 100` anywhere to declare `array` and reserve 100 bytes for it in the bss.  It's probably less confusing to just use `.bss`

---

That immediate constant is of course `0x0a6f6f66`, our string.  gcc has cleverly optimized the memcpy into a single 4-byte immediate store, since it has no use for the value(s) to still be in a register afterwards.  Remember that x86 is little-endian, so the `0x66` byte goes into `array+0` and `0x0a` goes into `array+3`. (gcc sucks at merging separate narrow stores other than with memcpy, though; see the godbolt link.  clang is better at this.)

---

In NASM syntax, you could even write it with a "string" as an integer constant.

```
mov    dword [array+off], `foo\n`    ;backquote for C-style \-escapes, unlike '' or ""
```

GNU `as` doesn't allow this, except with something that's harder to read than a hex constant + comment:

```
movl $('f' | 'o'<<8 | 'o'<<16 | '\n'<<24), array
```

GNU `as` syntax isn't as friendly for hand-written asm as NASM/YASM, but it's nice in some ways.  (`%reg` and so on makes it easy to see what's a register name and what's not.)

---

Speaking of immediates: **Your `size = 4` should be an immediate constant, not a load**.

```
##  size:  .int  4   # Don't need this stored in memory anywhere
.equ size, 4
...

movl   $array, %ecx   # The starting address of the string to print
movl   $size, %edx    # The number of bytes to print
```

Also note that the `movl $constant, (%ecx)` takes fewer bytes to encode than `movl $constant, array`, so you could save code bytes by getting `$array` into `%ecx` sooner and then using a simple register addressing mode.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how you're referring to the array members.  Use this instead:

```
movb   %ah, array + 0
movb   %al, array + 1
movb   %bh, array + 2 
movb   %bl, array + 3
```