# read and print number of command-line arguments in Linux assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, att, abi

I'm writing an assembly program with AT&T syntax (GAS compiling) on an Intel processor and on Ubuntu 14.

I'm trying to read the number of parameters passed by the user at the moment of program launch. For instance if user open his terminal and types `./programname x y z` I'd like that the `nParameters` variable assumes value 4 (because programname, x, y and z are parameter).

This is what I've done so far but I keep getting a segementation fault error.

```
.code32
.section .data

nParameters: .byte 0

.section .text
    .global _start

_start:
    popl %eax   #extract the number of parameters on the stack
    movl %eax,nParameters

movl $1,%eax
movl $0,%ebx
int $0x80
```

The error lies on this line: `movl %eax,nParameters` but I don't know why

Comment: `movl  %eax,nParameters` will try to move the contents of EAX  (32-bit) to nParameters which is defined by an 8-bit byte. Maybe you intended to make it `.long`. But I have a suspicion you might be creating a 64-bit executable with 32-bit code? Can you show us the commands you use to assemble and link to an executable?

Comment: @MichaelPetch  as -o programname.o programname.s and I link this way: ld -o test  programname programname.o.
I replaced .byte 0 with .long but still get the same error. Yes, I'm on a 64-bit system

Comment: I will make a guess you are on 64-bit linux? If you are, try assembling and linking with `as --32 -o programname.o programname.s` and `ld -melf_i386 -o programname programname.o` . That should generate a 32-bit executable.

Comment: @MichaelPetch  solved it. I assembled in this way: as --32 -gstabs and linked with ld -melf_i386. thank you for your time

Comment: The [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) has an entry on building 32bit code on a 64bit system.  It's in the FAQ section.  You'll also find links to the ABI docs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assembling 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit system (GNU toolchain)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain)

Comment: You needing to put `.code32` in front is a dead giveaway that you are assembling this as a 64 bit program :-)

Comment: The requirement for `-gstabs` is perplexing. I see no reason why it is necessary. Looking back you have this in your comment `ld -o test programname programname.o` . `-o test`  says what the outputfile will be so I don't know what the extra `programname` is right after.