# Program crashes when executed after linking to a directory

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86, dynamic-linking

The scenario is I try to re-link the program to a directory via `/proc` where these directories into an elf executable.

First, I create a directory with name test

```
$ mkdir test
```

Link to an hello binary

```
# ln /bin/ping test
# exit
```

Open a file descriptor to the target binary

```
$ exec 3< test
```

You know, this descriptor should now be accessible via `/proc`

```
$ ls -l /proc/$$/fd/3
lr-x------ 1 febri febri 64 Jul 17 11:09 /proc/2930/fd/3 -> /home/febri/test
```

Remove the directory previously created

```
$ rm -rf test
```

The `/proc` link should still exist, but now will be marked deleted.

```
$ ls -l /proc/$$/fd/3 
lr-x------ 1 febri febri 64 Jul 17 11:09 /proc/2930/fd/3 -> /home/febri/test (deleted)
```

Replace the directory with example payload like :

```
$ cat hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
printf("hello!\n");
return 0;
}
$ gcc -w -fPIC -shared -o test hello.c
$ ls -l test
-rwxrwxr-x 1 febri febri 6894 Jul 17 11:20 test
$ file test 
test: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=361c522d3d9db35ad24de9f3162f80f8a26c9c5b, not stripped
```

So, I running the linked program and the output is :

```
$ ./test
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

My question is :

Why the program crash when executed? if anyone can explain?

Comment: Hmmm, you created a library, not executable I think. (Shared flag)

Comment: Try removing the `-fPIC -shared` flags and see what happens.

Comment: downvoted for not even testing that your program works normally.  You could have just done `cp -a /bin/true ./test`.  (And since it'll be GNU `true` on Linux, it will even print stuff if run as `./test --version`)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the directories and/or symbolic links you messed around with have absolutely nothing to do with the segmentation fault you're facing. Let's look at the command line options you're using to compile `hello.c`:

- `-w`: Suppress all warnings. This is bad practice and will be the root of each and every single one of your bugs sooner or later. I've yet to find a good reason to suppress any warning. Anyways, this doesn't matter for this situation, as compiling a hello world program yields no warnings.
- `-fPIC`: Generate ]position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code).
- `-shared`: Generate a [shared library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries) instead of an executable.

So, you're attempting to execute a shared library, which is not intended to be executed! However, GCC marks the output file with the executable bit. That makes no sense at all... until you meet HP-UX's `mmap()` implementation.

Seemingly, due to [one of HP-UX's features](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48479/162880) (*cough* design flaws *cough*), the whole Unix(-like) family has inherited this convention of shared libraries being marked as executable, even though most of them will `SIGSEGV` if you actually try to execute them.

The actual cause of the segmentation fault, from the operating system's point of view, is an artifact of the way the [Executable and Linkable Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) was designed back in the late 1980's.

Curiously, it happens that shared libraries can indeed avoid `SEGV`'ing upon execution. However, black voodoo, such as [the GNU C Library's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223415/162880), shall be performed in order to do so. The consequences of performing such a ritual are agonizing. For instance, you're left with no way to initialize the C runtime, so you have to use direct `read()`'s and `write()`'s instead of `stdio`. Other runtime-supported subsystems, such as `malloc()` and friends, are out of question as well. Also, (because of no runtime support) there's no `main()`. You have to define your own entry point instead, and call `_exit(0)` explicitly.

**tl;dr**: Directories and symbolic links have nothing to do with the issue. You're attempting to execute a shared library, and, as that's not the expected behavior, you are `SIGSEGV`'d.

Comment: You actually can [use libc functions from `_start` if you call glibc's init functions (in the right order)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain/36901649#36901649).  This happens for you if you dynamically link to libc on Linux, but not with static linking.

Comment: Thank you for answering :))