# Hello, world in assembly language with Linux system calls?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, system-calls

1. I know that `int 0x80` is making interrupt in linux. But, I don't understand how this code works. Does it returning something?
2. What `$ - msg` standing for?

```
global _start

section .data
    msg db "Hello, world!", 0x0a
    len equ $ - msg

section .text
_start:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg
    mov edx, len
    int 0x80 ;What is this?
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80 ;and what is this?
```

Comment: 2. [How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47494744)

Comment: 1. [What does "int 0x80" mean in assembly code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817577/what-does-int-0x80-mean-in-assembly-code)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47494744) explains how `$ - msg` gets NASM to calculate the string length as an assemble-time constant for you, instead of hard-coding it.

---

Making a system call is done by putting arguments into registers, then running `int 0x80` (32-bit mode) or `syscall` (64-bit mode).  [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls (and user-space functions) on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6) and [The Definitive Guide to Linux System Calls](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/).

**Think of `int 0x80` as a way to "call" into the kernel, across the user/kernel privilege boundary.**  The kernel does stuff according to the values that were in registers when `int 0x80` executed, then eventually returns.  The return value is in EAX.

When execution reaches the kernel's entry point, it looks at EAX and dispatches to the right system call based on the call number in EAX.  Values from other registers are passed as function args to the kernel's handler for that system call.  (e.g. eax=4 / `int 0x80` will get the kernel to call its `sys_write` kernel function, implementing the POSIX `write` system call.)

And see also [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code/46087731#46087731) - that answer includes a look at the asm in the kernel entry point that is "called" by `int 0x80`.  (Also applies to 32-bit user-space, not just 64-bit where you shouldn't use `int 0x80`).

---

If you don't already know low-level Unix systems programming, you might want to just write functions in asm that take args and return a value (or update arrays via a pointer arg) and call them from C or C++ programs.  Then you can just worry about learning how to handle registers and memory, without also learning the POSIX system-call API and the ABI for using it.  That also makes it very easy to compare your code with compiler output for a C implementation.  Compilers usually do a pretty good job at making efficient code, but [are rarely perfect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354978/why-is-this-c-code-faster-than-my-hand-written-assembly-for-testing-the-collat/40355466#40355466).

libc provides wrapper functions for system calls, so compiler-generated code would `call write` rather than invoking it directly with `int 0x80` (or if you care about performance, `sysenter`).  (In x86-64 code, [use `syscall` for the 64-bit ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6).)  See also [`syscalls(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

System calls are documented in section 2 manual pages, like [`write(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html).  See the NOTES section for differences between the libc wrapper function and the underlying Linux system call.  Note that the wrapper for `sys_exit` is [`_exit(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html), not the [`exit(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) ISO C function that flushes stdio buffers and other cleanup first.  Actually `_exit()` uses the `exit_group` system call that [ends all threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434609/why-do-i-get-a-zombie-when-i-link-assembly-code-without-stdlib).  `exit(3)` also uses that, because there's no downside in a single-threaded process.

Given the system-call calling convention and the C man pages, you can see which arg goes in which register; there are some web pages with tables of system calls and registers, but you don't need them.

This code makes 2 system calls:

- [`sys_write(1, "Hello, World!\n", sizeof(...));`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)
- [`sys_exit(0);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html)

I commented it heavily (to the point where it it's starting to obscure the actual code without color syntax highlighting).  This is an attempt to point things out to total beginners, not how you should comment your code normally.

```
section .text             ; Executable code goes in the .text section
global _start             ; The linker looks for this symbol to set the process entry point, so execution start here
;;;a name followed by a colon defines a symbol.  The global _start directive modifies it so it's a global symbol, not just one that we can CALL or JMP to from inside the asm.
;;; note that _start isn't really a "function".  You can't return from it, and the kernel passes argc, argv, and env differently than main() would expect.
 _start:
    ;;; write(1, msg, len);
    ; Start by moving the arguments into registers, where the kernel will look for them
    mov     edx,len       ; 3rd arg goes in edx: buffer length
    mov     ecx,msg       ; 2nd arg goes in ecx: pointer to the buffer
    ;Set output to stdout (goes to your terminal, or wherever you redirect or pipe)
    mov     ebx,1         ; 1st arg goes in ebx: Unix file descriptor. 1 = stdout, which is normally connected to the terminal.

    mov     eax,4         ; system call number (from SYS_write / __NR_write from unistd_32.h).
    int     0x80          ; generate an interrupt, activating the kernel's system-call handling code.  64-bit code uses a different instruction, different registers, and different call numbers.
    ;; eax = return value, all other registers unchanged.

    ;;;Second, exit the process.  There's nothing to return to, so we can't use a ret instruction (like we could if this was main() or any function with a caller)
    ;;; If we don't exit, execution continues into whatever bytes are next in the memory page,
    ;;; typically leading to a segmentation fault because the padding 00 00 decodes to  add [eax],al.

    ;;; _exit(0);
    xor     ebx,ebx       ; first arg = exit status = 0.  (will be truncated to 8 bits).  Zeroing registers is a special case on x86, and mov ebx,0 would be less efficient.
                      ;; leaving out the zeroing of ebx would mean we exit(1), i.e. with an error status, since ebx still holds 1 from earlier.
    mov     eax,1         ; put __NR_exit into eax
    int     0x80          ;Execute the Linux function

section     .rodata       ; Section for read-only constants

             ;; msg is a label, and in this context doesn't need to be msg:.  It could be on a separate line.
             ;; db = Data Bytes: assemble some literal bytes into the output file.
msg     db  'Hello, world!',0xa     ; ASCII string constant plus a newline (0x10)

             ;;  No terminating zero byte is needed, because we're using write(), which takes a buffer + length instead of an implicit-length string.
             ;; To make this a C string that we could pass to puts or strlen, we'd need a terminating 0 byte. (e.g. "...", 0x10, 0)

len     equ $ - msg       ; Define an assemble-time constant (not stored by itself in the output file, but will appear as an immediate operand in insns that use it)
                          ; Calculate len = string length.  subtract the address of the start
                          ; of the string from the current position ($)
  ;; equivalently, we could have put a str_end: label after the string and done   len equ str_end - str
```

Notice that we *don't* store the string length in data memory anywhere.  It's an assemble-time constant, so it's more efficient to have it as an immediate operand than a load.  We could also have pushed the string data onto the stack with three `push imm32` instructions, but bloating the code-size too much isn't a good thing.

---

On Linux, you can save this file as `Hello.asm` and **build a 32-bit executable from it with these commands**:

```
nasm -felf32 Hello.asm                  # assemble as 32-bit code.  Add -Worphan-labels -g -Fdwarf  for debug symbols and warnings
gcc -static -nostdlib -m32 Hello.o -o Hello     # link without CRT startup code or libc, making a static binary
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain/36901649#36901649) for more details on building assembly into 32 or 64-bit static or dynamically linked Linux executables, for NASM/YASM syntax or GNU AT&T syntax with GNU `as` directives.  (Key point: make sure to use `-m32` or equivalent when building 32-bit code on a 64-bit host, or you will have confusing problems at run-time.)

---

**You can trace its execution with `strace` to see the system calls it makes**:

```
$ strace ./Hello 
execve("./Hello", ["./Hello"], [/* 72 vars */]) = 0
[ Process PID=4019 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
write(1, "Hello, world!\n", 14Hello, world!
)         = 14
_exit(0)                                = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Compare this with the trace for a dynamically linked process (like gcc makes from hello.c, or from running `strace /bin/ls`) to get an idea just how much stuff happens under the hood for dynamic linking and C library startup.

The trace on stderr and the regular output on stdout are both going to the terminal here, so they interfere in the line with the `write` system call.  Redirect or trace to a file if you care.  Notice how this lets us easily see the syscall return values without having to add code to print them, and is actually even easier than using a regular debugger (like gdb) to single-step and look at `eax` for this.  See the bottom of the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for gdb asm tips.  (The rest of the tag wiki is full of links to good resources.)

The x86-64 version of this program would be extremely similar, passing the same args to the same system calls, just in different registers and with `syscall` instead of `int 0x80`.  See the bottom of [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code) for a working example of writing a string and exiting in 64-bit code.

---

Related: [A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux](http://www.muppetlabs.com/%7Ebreadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html).  The smallest binary file you can run that just makes an exit() system call.  That is about minimizing the binary size, not the source size or even just the number of instructions that actually run.

---

*I originally wrote this (except the first sentence) for [SO Docs (topic ID: 1164, example ID: 19078)](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z), rewriting a basic less-well-commented example by @runner.*  This looks like a better place to put it than as [part of my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550402/what-parts-of-this-helloworld-assembly-code-are-essential-if-i-were-to-write-the/39551489#39551489) where I had previously moved it after the SO docs experiment ended.

Comment: Appreciate!! It helps me a lot!!