# About the memory layout of programs in Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, memory-layout

I have some questions about the memory layout of a program in Linux. I know from various sources (I'm reading "Programming from the Ground Up") that each section is loaded into it's own region of memory. The text section loads first at virtual address 0x8048000, the data section is loaded immediately after that, next is the bss section, followed by the heap and the stack.

To experiment with the layout I made this program in assembly. First it prints the addresses of some labels and calculates the system break point. Then it enters into an infinite loop. The loop increments a pointer and then it tries to access the memory at that address, at some point a segmentation fault will exit the program (I did this intentionally).

This is the program:

```
.section .data

start_data:
str_mem_access:
.ascii "Accessing address: 0x%x\n\0"
str_data_start:
.ascii "Data section start at: 0x%x\n\0"
str_data_end:
.ascii "Data section ends at: 0x%x\n\0"
str_bss_start:
.ascii "bss section starts at: 0x%x\n\0"
str_bss_end:
.ascii "bss section ends at: 0x%x\n\0"
str_text_start:
.ascii "text section starts at: 0x%x\n\0"
str_text_end:
.ascii "text section ends at: 0x%x\n\0"
str_break:
.ascii "break at: 0x%x\n\0"
end_data:

.section .bss

start_bss:
.lcomm buffer, 500
.lcomm buffer2, 250
end_bss:

.section .text
start_text:

.globl _start
_start:

# print address of start_text label
pushl $start_text
pushl $str_text_start
call printf
addl $8, %esp
# print address of end_text label
pushl $end_text
pushl $str_text_end
call printf
addl $8, %esp
# print address of start_data label
pushl $start_data
pushl $str_data_start
call printf
addl $8, %esp
# print address of end_data label
pushl $end_data
pushl $str_data_end
call printf
addl $8, %esp
# print address of start_bss label
pushl $start_bss
pushl $str_bss_start
call printf
addl $8, %esp
# print address of end_bss label
pushl $end_bss
pushl $str_bss_end
call printf
addl $8, %esp
# get last usable virtual memory address
movl $45, %eax
movl $0, %ebx
int $0x80

incl %eax # system break address
# print system break
pushl %eax
pushl $str_break
call printf
addl $4, %esp

movl $start_text, %ebx

loop:
# print address
pushl %ebx
pushl $str_mem_access
call printf
addl $8, %esp

# access address
# segmentation fault here
movb (%ebx), %dl

incl %ebx

jmp loop

end_loop:
movl $1, %eax
movl $0, %ebx
int $0x80

end_text:
```

And this the relevant parts of the output (this is Debian 32bit):

```
text section starts at: 0x8048190
text section ends at: 0x804823b
Data section start at: 0x80492ec
Data section ends at: 0x80493c0
bss section starts at: 0x80493c0
bss section ends at: 0x80493c0
break at: 0x83b4001
Accessing address: 0x8048190
Accessing address: 0x8048191
Accessing address: 0x8048192
[...]
Accessing address: 0x8049fff
Accessing address: 0x804a000
Violación de segmento
```

My questions are:

1) Why is my program starting at address 0x8048190 instead of 0x8048000? With this I guess that the instruction at the "_start" label is not the first thing to load, so what's between the addresses 0x8048000 and 0x8048190?

2) Why is there a gap between the end of the text section and the start of the data section?

3) The bss start and end addresses are the same. I assume that the two buffers are stored somewhere else, is this correct?

4) If the system break point is at 0x83b4001, why I get the segmentation fault earlier at 0x804a000?

Comment: Nearly completely off-topic, if you've never [read this, take a look at it](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) -- it's a great read.

Comment: Note that the ELF loader only cares about *segments* of the executable.  There's a 1:1 mapping in many cases, like the `.text` section (after linking) being the only thing in the text segment.  The linker combines sections like `.rodata` into `.text`.  Also, "the heap" isn't really a thing that exists, and is more of a concept (allocations with mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS) aren't contiguous with the `brk`).  I'm not sure whether people consider the BSS and static data as part of the heap.  Also not sure if Linux puts the initial `brk` right after the BSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're building this with `gcc -m32 -nostartfiles segment-bounds.S` or similar, so you have a 32-bit dynamic binary.  (You don't need `-m32` if you're actually using a 32-bit system, but most people that want to test this will have 64-bit systems.)

My 64-bit Ubuntu 15.10 system gives slightly different numbers from your program for a few things, but the overall pattern of behaviour is the same.  (Different kernel, or just [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), explains this.  The brk address varies wildly, for example, with values like `0x9354001` or `0x82a8001`)

---

> 1) Why is my program starting at address 0x8048190 instead of 0x8048000?

If you build a static binary, your `_start` will be at 0x8048000.

We can see from `readelf -a a.out` that `0x8048190` is the start of the .text section.  But it isn't at the start of the text segment that's mapped to a page.  (pages are 4096B, and Linux requires mappings to be aligned on 4096B boundaries of file position, so with the file laid out this way, it wouldn't be possible for `execve` to map `_start` to the start of a page.  I think the Off column is position within the file.)

Presumably the other sections in the text segment before the `.text` section are read-only data that's needed by the dynamic linker, so it makes sense to have it mapped into memory in the same page.

```
## part of readelf -a output
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS        08048114 000114 000013 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 2] .note.gnu.build-i NOTE            08048128 000128 000024 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 3] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH        0804814c 00014c 000018 04   A  4   0  4
  [ 4] .dynsym           DYNSYM          08048164 000164 000020 10   A  5   1  4
  [ 5] .dynstr           STRTAB          08048184 000184 00001c 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 6] .gnu.version      VERSYM          080481a0 0001a0 000004 02   A  4   0  2
  [ 7] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED         080481a4 0001a4 000020 00   A  5   1  4
  [ 8] .rel.plt          REL             080481c4 0001c4 000008 08  AI  4   9  4
  [ 9] .plt              PROGBITS        080481d0 0001d0 000020 04  AX  0   0 16
  [10] .text             PROGBITS        080481f0 0001f0 0000ad 00  AX  0   0  1         ########## The .text section
  [11] .eh_frame         PROGBITS        080482a0 0002a0 000000 00   A  0   0  4
  [12] .dynamic          DYNAMIC         08049f60 000f60 0000a0 08  WA  5   0  4
  [13] .got.plt          PROGBITS        0804a000 001000 000010 04  WA  0   0  4
  [14] .data             PROGBITS        0804a010 001010 0000d4 00  WA  0   0  1
  [15] .bss              NOBITS          0804a0e8 0010e4 0002f4 00  WA  0   0  8
  [16] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 0010e4 0000a2 00      0   0  1
  [17] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 001188 0002b0 10     18  38  4
  [18] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 001438 000123 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)
```

---

> 2) Why is there a gap between the end of the text section and the start of the data section?

Why not?  They have to be in different segments of the executable, so mapped to different pages.  (Text is read-only and executable, and can be MAP_SHARED.  Data is read-write and has to be MAP_PRIVATE.  BTW, in Linux the default is for data to also be executable.)

Leaving a gap makes room for the dynamic linker to map the text segment of shared libraries next to the text of the executable.  It also means an out-of-bounds array index into the data section is more likely to segfault.  (Earlier and noisier failure is always easier to debug).

---

3) The bss start and end addresses are the same. I assume that the two buffers are stored somewhere else, is this correct?

That's interesting.  They're in the bss, but IDK why the current position isn't affected by `.lcomm` labels.  Probably they go in a different subsection before linking, since you used `.lcomm` instead of `.comm`.  If I use use `.skip` or [`.zero`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Zero.html#Zero) to reserve space, I get the results you expected:

```
.section .bss
start_bss:
#.lcomm buffer, 500
#.lcomm buffer2, 250
buffer:  .skip 500
buffer2: .skip 250
end_bss:
```

[`.lcomm`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Lcomm.html) puts things in the BSS even if you don't switch to that section.  i.e. it doesn't care what the current section is, and maybe doesn't care about or affect what the current position in the `.bss` section is.  TL:DR: when you switch to the `.bss` manually, use `.zero` or `.skip`, not `.comm` or `.lcomm`.

---

> 4) If the system break point is at 0x83b4001, why I get the segmentation fault earlier at 0x804a000?

That tells us that there are unmapped pages between the text segment and the brk.  (Your loop starts with `ebx = $start_text`, so it faults at the on the first unmapped page after the text segment).  Besides the hole in virtual address space between text and data, there's probably also other holes beyond the data segment.

Memory protection has page granularity (4096B), so the first address to fault will always be the first byte of a page.

Comment: I am building it with `as break.S -o break.o && ld -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o break break.o -lc` inside a Debian 3.5 i386 virtual machine (Host is Ubuntu 15.10 64bit).

Comment: @saga.x:  Yes, that's equivalent to `gcc -m32 -nostartfiles`.  Why would you bother with a 32-bit VM?  Just `gcc -m32`, or `as` and `ld` [with the right args](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain/36901649#36901649) on your Ubuntu system, like I explain in that answer I linked.  Running 32-bit code on a 64-bit kernel works flawlessly, and Ubuntu's multilib packages include all the necessary 32-bit libraries.

Comment: Ok, I installed the `gcc-multilib` package and builded it wiht `gcc -m32 -nostartfiles`, it works. I also searched something about the ASLR and if i execute as root `sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0` the break point address never changes, it's fixed at 0x804a001 which is the same address of the segmentation fault I got. I should read a lot more about how Linux works and the memory-management to really understand better this topic, very interesting but I am new to this. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: @saga.x:  Yup, you can disable ASLR, but you don't usually need that repeatability between runs when debugging with gdb and /proc/pid/maps.  Interesting that it happens to use the same brk as your 32-bit kernel without ASLR.  There are differences between 32 and 64-bit kernels, though:  IIRC, 32-bit processes under a 64-bit kernel can use the entire 4GiB of virtual address space, but 32-bit kernels reserve the upper 1 or 2GiB of every process's virtual address space for mapping kernel memory during system calls.  (So you can only allocate up to 3GiB in a 32-bit process on a 32-bit kernel.)

Comment: And yes there is a crapload of stuff to understand!  I've been using Linux as my desktop since before AMD64 exists (nearly 20 years now), so I've been able to pick up a lot of things gradually, instead of having all the complexity at once.  I already knew a LOT of stuff before I started seriously messing around with asm.  Anyway, your questions are a *lot* better than the usual boring "I don't understand anything about asm but I wrote this program.  Debug it for me" kind of questions that we see a lot of on SO.  Keep up the interesting questions :)

Comment: @saga.x: Also, I learned a lot about Linux from reading the help for various options while configuring / compiling my own kernel back in the day, when computers were slow and disk/RAM was small and that was worth doing (P233MMX with 64MB of RAM, I think :)  (e.g. there was an option to choose whether you wanted a 2G:2G kernel:user split or 1:3.)