# getting error while executing code of assembly language on nasm Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: gcc, assembly, nasm

I tried it so many time, but while executing the assembly language code on terminal through nasm to make an executable file, then I stuck here, any one can help me to get out of this problem..

i tried these command line to execute it.

```
nasm -f elf helloworld.asm
```

to make run the file then i want to make an object file to execute it so I used this command

```
id -s -o helloworld helloworld.o
```

but the second command is not running because there are no command options such as `-s` or `-o`.

Please help me and follow the image thanks

[image]

Comment: The linker is `ld` (lower case L), not `id`.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain/36901649#36901649) for more info about building 32 or 64-bit binaries that define `_start` or `main`, with / without the standard library.  Also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: Also, your question title is wrong.  You haven't executed any code you wrote in asm yet.  You're running into trouble while *building* it.  The difference between compiler / assembler errors and run-time errors is important if you're going to ask future questions.

Comment: stiil I am getting this error    ld: i386 architecture of input file 'helloworld.o' is incompatible with i386.x86-64boutput

Comment: Your 64-bit Linux tools default to building 64-bit binaries, but you told NASM to assemble a 32-bit object file.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain/36901649#36901649.  That's from [the x86 tag wiki's FAQ section](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)