# Linker error when calling printf from _start

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, linker-errors, ld

I tried to write simple program without *main*

```
    segment .data
fmt db "test", 0xa, 0

    segment .text
    global _start
    extern printf
_start:
    lea rdi, [fmt] ; print simple string
    xor eax, eax
    call printf
    mov eax, 60    ; exit successfully
    xor edi, edi
    syscall
```

Compile:

```
yasm -f elf64 main.s; ld -o main main.o
```

Got

```
main.o: In function `_start':
main.s:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `printf'
```

How should one fix this?

Comment: because printf is provided by the CRT and you are not either initializating nor linking it.

Comment: Did you link against the libc?

Comment: No, ld -o main main.o. I thought program links dynamically to libc at runtime.
Correct please, if I am wrong.

Comment: @BulatM. Yes, they do, but you still need to tell the linker to do so. How else can it know that it can find `printf` in the libc?

Comment: @MichaelPetch It seems like ld chooses an incorrect interpreter name by default.

Comment: @MichaelPetch It uses `/lib/ld64.so.1`, which is not present.

Comment: @Michael, it works. Could you please show how to dispense with compiler using only assembler and linker tools? Want to learn how that basic tools work to get proper understanding.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I was critizing your sentence “It doesn't use one at all.” No, it does try to use a dynamic loader, namely `/lib/ld64.so.1`. It's just that that loader is not present.

Comment: I do not have `/lib/ld64.so.1` but have `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` which is symlink to `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Cause of Your Error

The reason you get `undefined reference to printf` while linking is because you didn't link against the *C* library. As well, when using your own `_start` label as an entry point there are other issues that must be overcome as discussed below.

---

### Using LIBC without C Runtime Startup Code

To make sure you are using the appropriate dynamic linker at runtime and link against the *C* library you can use *GCC* as a frontend for *LD*. To supply your own `_start` label and avoid the *C* runtime startup code use the `-nostartfiles` option. Although I don't recommend this method, you can link with:

```
gcc -m64 -nostartfiles main.o -o main
```

If you wish to use *LD* you can do it by using a specific dynamic linker and link against the *C* library with `-lc`. To link x86_64 code you can use:

```
ld -melf_x86_64 --dynamic-linker=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 main.o -lc -o main
```

If you had been compiling and linking for 32-bit, then the linking could have been done with:

```
ld -melf_i386 --dynamic-linker=/lib/ld-linux.so.2 main.o -lc -o main
```

---

### Preferred Method Using C Runtime Startup Code

Since you are using the *C* library you should consider linking against the *C* runtime. This method also works if you were to create a static executable. The best way to use the *C* library is to rename your `_start` label to `main` and then use *GCC* to link:

```
gcc -m64 main.o -o main
```

Doing it this way allows you to exit your program by returning (using *RET*) from `main` the same way a *C* program ends. This also has the advantage of flushing standard output when the program exits.

---

### Flushing output buffers / exit

Using `syscall` with *EAX*=60 to exit won't flush the output buffers. Because of this you may find yourself having to add a newline character on your output to see output before exiting. This is still not a guarantee you will see what you output with `printf`. Rather than the sys_exit *SYSCALL* you might consider calling the *C* library function `exit`. the *MAN PAGE* for `exit` says:

> All open stdio(3) streams are flushed and closed.  Files created by tmpfile(3) are removed.

I'd recommend replacing the sys_exit *SYSCALL* with:

```
extern exit

xor edi, edi    ; In 64-bit code RDI is 1st argument = return value
call exit
```

Comment: it works. Could you please show how to dispense with compiler using only assembler and linker tools? Want to learn how those basic tools work to get proper understanding not to just use stopgap without understanding.

Comment: @BulatM. I edited the answer

Comment: Works. Could you please elaborate what linker was used when doing `ld -o main main.o` and why bash gives error(very strange)?

Comment: @BulatM. Bash gave the strange error because no dynamic loader was specified when creating the executable.

Comment: Interesting, beforehand I thought that shells just fork and execute one of functions from exec family without bothering with loaders.

Answer (score 1):

The `printf` function is provided by the C standard library, `libc`. To use it, you need to pass `-lc` to the linker:

```
ld -o main main.o -lc
```

I recommend you to use the C compiler as a frontend for the linker to get possible other flags right, too:

```
cc -o main -nostartfiles main.o
```

Note that since your program doesn't initialize the C standard library, e parts of it may not work as expected. If you want to use the C standard library in your assembly program, I recommend you to make your assembly program start from `main` and to link it by invoking the C compiler:

```
yasm -f elf64 main.s
cc -o main main.o
```

Comment: I do `ld -o main main.o -lc`
Links successfully.
Then try to execute `./main` - it fails
`-bash: ./main: No such file or directory`
It is not related to linking, but do not know where is the problem.
It is there:
`ls -al
-rwxrwxr-x 1 name name 2832 Sep 18 15:00 main`

Comment: @BulatM. Very interesting. I'm not sure what the problem is, let me investigate.

Comment: @BulatM.: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain/36901649#36901649) re: getting the right ELF interpreter when using `ld` directly, and more generally how to build static / dynamic binaries with/without libc, from source that defines main or _start.

Comment: I should really retitle that question, since the canonical answer I wrote there is the answer to a boatload of 64-bit-only questions too.