# ld linker says undefined reference to printf

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, linker-errors

When i try to link my assembly program ld linker says

> **undefined reference to printf**

I tried writing **extern printf** in my code but gnu assembler says no such instruction.

**my code is**

```
.section .data
Dd: .ascii "hello"

.section .text
.global _start
_start:
.global main
main:
    movq $0, %rax
    movq $Dd, %rdi
    call printf
    ret
    movq $60, %rax
    syscall
```

Linker say undefined reference to 'printf'

Even i tried to link `-dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2`

Comment: How do you assemble and link your program?

Comment: `printf` is in libc.  Use `gcc hello.S` to assemble and link your program with libc and CRT start code that will call your `main`.  There's no point in using `ld` directly unless you're writing your own `_start`.

Comment: as hello.s -o hello.o &&  ld -o hello hello.o,

Comment: But how to do it if i write my own _start:

Comment: Should be the same - your `_start:` should take precedence over the one from the C runtime. Did you try it?

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [Linking a C program directly with ld fails with undefined reference to \`\_\_libc\_csu\_fini\`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6656317) which explains linking a normal `main` like a C compiler might produce, using `ld`.

Comment: @CarlNorum: No, your own `_start` will *conflict with* CRT start code if you link it.  If you write your own `_start`, assemble + link with `gcc -no-pie -nostartfiles` or `gcc -no-pie -nostdlib`.

Comment: I just tried it here - no problems on my test. It's a mac, though, so the linker behaviour might be different.

Comment: Actually my test might be bad - looks like `start` isn't what I think it's labeled.

Comment: @imComputerGeek: Writing your own `_start` is different from writing your own `main`, even in terms of how you build an executable out of it.  So that would be a separate question.  [Linker error when calling printf from \_start](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39557237)