# Assembly add with hex and multiple argument, then compare

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, att

```
add -0x4(%r12), %eax
cmp %eax, %r12
```

I'm given these two lines in assembly.

My guess is that you subtract 4 from the value in r12, then add that to eax.

Does r12 continue to be -4 from it's original, or does the value keep it's original value?

For example, if r12 = 5, and eax = 3, the add function would result in  eax = 4;
would r12 still be 5 or would it be 1?

Comment: I kinda want to edit the title into something generic, now that I've posted an answer that shows how to test any arbitrary code fragment.  Hrm.  That's normally the opposite of what a good title should be.

Answer (score 1):

You could single step this yourself in gdb to see what it did.  Set up gdb to show you register changed by the last single-step (e.g. `layout reg`, see the bottom of the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)).

Since `%r12` needs to be a valid pointer for the source operand for the ADD, put this in `foo.S`:

```
.globl _start
_start:
    mov   %rsp, %r12               # added this instruction: r12 is now a valid pointer to stack memory, since we copy the stack pointer into it

    add   -0x4(%r12), %eax
    # cmp   %eax, %r12             # operand-size mismatch is an error

    cmp   %eax, %r12d              # 32-bit compare
    cmp   %rax, %r12               # 64-bit compare.  upper 32 of RAX is zero from writing EAX in the add instruction

    # your program will segfault here because we don't make an exit() system call, and instead keep executing whatever bytes are next in memory.
```

Assemble it with [`gcc -g -nostdlib foo.S`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain/36901649#36901649) to make a static binary.  [_start is the default entry point](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html).

Run `gdb ./a.out`:

```
(gdb) layout reg
(gdb) b _start
(gdb) r
(gdb) si          # step instruction, 
# repeat as necessary and watch gdb highlight changed registers.
```

I like `set disassembly-flavor intel` instead of AT&T syntax, but if you like (or want/need to learn AT&T syntax), then don't do that.

Hint, [CMP doesn't modify either of its operands](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMP.html), and the ADD only uses R12 as the addressing mode to load 4 bytes of source data from.

The final value of EAX depends on what was in memory.

Answer (score 0):

This does not change `r12`; it simply uses it to calculate an address.