# Message while debugging using gdb: Single stepping until exit from function _start

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, nasm

I am writing assembly language program using nasm on linux. The problem is during debugging using gdb it does not step inside the _start function and gives the message  "Single stepping until exit from function _start,"

Also, when I set break points after line 1 it says:

```
(gdb) break 2  
Note: breakpoints 1 and 2 also set at pc 0x4000b0.  
Breakpoint 3 at 0x4000b0: file new3.asm, line 2.  

(gdb) break 3  
Note: breakpoints 1, 2 and 3 also set at pc 0x4000b0.  
Breakpoint 4 at 0x4000b0: file new3.asm, line 3.
```

I am assembling and linking it using the commands :

```
nasm -g  -f elf64 new3.asm  
ld  -g new3.o
```

then i debug it using `gdb new3.out`. The gdb version is 7.11.1

the program is below :

```
section .text  
    global _start   ;must be declared for linker (ld)   
_start:             ;tells linker entry point  
    call sum  
    mov edx,len     ;message length  
    mov ecx,msg     ;message to write  
    mov ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)  
    mov eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)  
    int 0x80        ;call kernel  
    mov eax,1       ;system call number (sys_exit)  
    int 0x80        ;call kernel  

sum:  
   mov     eax, ecx  
   add     eax, edx  
   add     eax, '0'  
   ret  
section .data  
msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ;string to be printed  
len equ $ - msg     ;length of the string
```

How i can step inside the _start for debugging and what is the meaning of this?

```
(gdb) break 3
Note: breakpoints 1, 2 and 3 also set at pc 0x4000b0.
Breakpoint 4 at 0x4000b0: file new3.asm, line 3.
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the `int 0x80` 32-bit system call ABI from 64-bit code.  Use `syscall` instead.  It has different call numbers, and different register usage.

Answer (score 3):

**Use `nasm -f elf64 -F dwarf -g  new3.asm` to make dwarf debug info**, not the default (stabs).  (Use `nasm -felf64 -y` to see the default).  `yasm -felf64 -gdwarf2 new3.asm` works, too.  (Actually single stepping works even if you leave out `-gdwarf2` for yasm: I guess it includes enough by default).

Then gdb will be able to single-step by source lines instead of just by instructions (`stepi`).  You don't need `ld -g`, that doesn't do anything.

You should probably also link with `gcc -nostdlib -g new3.o`, instead of ld directly.  If you added any dynamic libs to your ld command line, you'd have a broken binary (because ld's default ELF interpreter path isn't useful on modern x86-64 multiarch systems).  See [Building an executable from asm source that defines `_start` vs. `main`, static or dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain/36901649#36901649).

Also, don't use the `int 0x80` 32-bit ABI from 64-bit code.

---

Use `stepi` (or `si`) to step by instructions instead of by source lines.

Use `b *0x4000b0` to set breakpoints based on numeric address.  Or use label names, like `b _start` to set a breakpoint at the entry point.

See the bottom of the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for some more tips on debugging asm with gdb.

---

**The first instruction in your file is on line 4, so it's not surprising** that `b 1` and `b 4` both set a breakpoint on the CALL instruction.

`b 5` does set a breakpoint on the instruction after CALL. This part does work even when gdb only has STABS debug info (not DWARF or DWARF2), but single-stepping doesn't.  IDK why.

```
(gdb) b _start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4000b0
(gdb) b 5
Breakpoint 2 at 0x4000b5: file new3.asm, line 5.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/peter/src/SO/a.out

Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004000b0 in _start ()
```

Comment: Update: modern GDB has a `starti` command that makes it easy to run with a hidden breakpoint before the first user-space instruction, even in a PIE executable where the entry-point address isn't known until you run.  (And a similar `start` command that looks for a function called `main` and sets a breakpoint there.)