# How to fix getting "sigsegv" when trying to debug a simple nasm assembly program

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am running a virtual box on win10 64 bit home host. On the virtual box i have installed ubuntu 18.04 64 bit.

I downloaded a sample assembly program from the site related to the book im learning from "Assembly language step-by-step".

this is the program:

```
; vim: ft=nasm
;
; Build using these commands (works on 32-bit Linux)
;    nasm -f elf -g -F stabs eatsyscall.asm
;    ld -o eatsyscall eatsyscall.o
;
; Build on 64-bit Linux: (Linux 3.13.7-1-ARCH #1 x86_64 GNU/Linux)
;    nasm -f elf64 -g -F stabs eatsyscall.asm
;    ld -o eatsyscall eatsyscall.o
;
; Build on OSX (although the instructions are not valid for its architecture)
;    nasm -f macho eatsyscall.asm 
;    ld -arch i386 -macosx_version_min 10.5 -no_pie -e _start -o eatsyscall eatsyscall.o
;

section .data                 ; contains initialized data

EatMsg: db "Eat at Joe's!",10
EatLen  equ $ - EatMsg

section .bss                  ; contains uninitialized data

section .text                 ; contains code

global _start                 ; entry point found by linker (default is _start)

_start:
  nop                         ; needed to allow debugging with gdb - lldb not properly working ATM
  mov eax,4                   ; Specify sys_write syscall
  mov ebx,1                   ; specify file descriptor: stdout
  mov ecx,EatMsg              ; pass message offset
  mov edx,EatLen              ; pass message length
  int 80H                     ; make syscall to output text to stdout

  mov eax,1                   ; specify exit syscall
  mov ebx,0                   ; return code of zero
  int 80H                     ; make syscall to terminate program
```

when i try to debug it with either kdbg or directly with gdb the same 2 weird things happen (weird to me but might just be my complete inexperience):

1. when i try to put a break point at line 29 "mov eax, 4" - 
   the debugger doesnt stop there. It stops only if i put 3 breakpoints one after the other starting at the above mentioned line.
2. when the debugger does stop, if i try to do a step-into command the debugger tells me that the program terminated with the "SIGSEGV" signal - segmentation fault. The debugging program doesnt terminate but the program i am trying to debug.

I tried searching for this online but couldnt find anything related to the problem im experiencing.

All help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!

Appearantly the problem was using the wrong debug info type.
The command that solved this is:

```
nasm -f elf64 -g -F dwarf eatsyscall.asm -o eatsyscall.o
```

instead of:

```
nasm -f elf64 -g -F stabs eatsyscall.asm -o eatsyscall.o
```

The answer to this question gave me the lead:
[Message while debugging using gdb: Single stepping until exit from function _start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39667931/message-while-debugging-using-gdb-single-stepping-until-exit-from-function-sta?rq=1)