# Trivial macOS assembly 64-bit program has incorrect stack alignment

Tags: macos, assembly

I'm trying to create a trivial console assembly program with arguments. Here's the code:

```
.section __TEXT,__text

.globl _main

_main:

    movl    $0, %edi
    callq   _exit
```

Here's the compile and link script:

```
as test.s -o test.o
ld test.o -e _main -o test -lc
```

Now the program either fails with a segmentation fault, or executes without error, depending on the argument count:

```
$ ./test
Segmentation fault: 11
$ ./test 1
$ ./test 1 2
$ ./test 1 2 3
Segmentation fault: 11
$ ./test 1 2 3 4
$ ./test 1 2 3 4 5
Segmentation fault: 11
```

And so on.

Under the LLDB I see a more informative error:

```
Process 16318 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
    frame #0: 0x00007fffad14b2fa libdyld.dylib`stack_not_16_byte_aligned_error
libdyld.dylib`stack_not_16_byte_aligned_error:
->  0x7fffad14b2fa <+0>: movdqa %xmm0, (%rsp)
    0x7fffad14b2ff <+5>: int3   

libdyld.dylib`_dyld_func_lookup:
    0x7fffad14b300 <+0>: pushq  %rbp
    0x7fffad14b301 <+1>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
```

Indeed, if I stop the execution at the first line of the program, I see that the stack is not 16-byte aligned for some argument count, while it is aligned for another. Although the [System V ABI for AMD64](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf) states that:

> The stack pointer holds the address of the byte with lowest address
>   which is part of the stack. It is guaranteed to be 16-byte aligned at
>   process entry.

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like OS X is violating the ABI for some lengths of args.  (Hopefully they never claimed to follow exactly that ABI?  I thought they did, too, though.)  Have you tried without libc, just checking stack alignment yourself (with a debugger) on process entry to a statically-linked binary that exits with a `syscall` directly?  (Or set exit status = `rsp & 0xf` and `./test 1 2 3 ; echo $?` to see the stack alignment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess on OS X the kernel doesn't guarantee a stack alignment on entry to `main`. You have to manually align the stack. Fortunately, this is rather easy, just zero-out the least four bits of the stack pointer. In case you need to fetch the argument vector or other data, make sure to store the original stack pointer somewhere:

```
_main:
    mov %rsp,%rax    # copy original stack pointer
    and $-16,%rsp    # align stack to 16 bytes
    push %rax        # save original stack pointer
    push %rbp        # establish...
    mov %rsp,%rbp    # ...stack frame
    ...              # business logic here
    leave            # tear down stack frame
    pop %rsp         # restore original stack pointer
    ...              # exit process
```

You also need to mentally keep track of your stack alignment. It might be easier to have `main` do nothing but the stack alignment and then calling your actual main function so you can use a normal stack frame in it:

```
_main:
    mov %rsp,%rbx    # save original stack pointer
    and $-16,%rsp    # align stack to 16 bytes
    call _my_main    # call actual main function
    mov %rbx,%rsp    # restore original stack pointer
    ...              # exit process
```

For your particular example program, you can just use this minimal code:

```
_main:
    and $-16,%rsp    # align stack to 16 bytes
    xor %edi,%edi    # set exit status to zero
    call _exit       # exit program
```

Comment: Looks like it was the case. I based my code on the second snippet, and now the manual alignment works. Thanks!

Comment: System V Application Binary Interface
AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement
(With LP64 and ILP32 Programming Models)
Draft Version 0.99.8: *%rsp The stack pointer holds the address of the byte with lowest address which
is part of the stack. It is guaranteed to be 16-byte aligned at process entry.* Notably this is different than the `(%rsp+8)%16 == 0` for normal functions.

Comment: @EOF: That's exactly what you want for making a function call.  At the start of a normal function, you need a dummy `push`, or `sub $8, %rsp`, before a `call`.  Or `jmp exit` to tailcall.  Because the stack is supposed to be 16B-aligned before you run a `call` instruction, so the args are aligned.  Also, note the OP's error message: `0x...a` is not 0 or 8.

Comment: @Fuz: The OP is using `_main` as an alternate name for `_start`; note the `ld test.o -e _main -o test -lc` to set the ELF entry point to `_main`.  So there's nothing to return to.  Very poor choice of name, IMO, but the state of the stack is the kernel-startup state (or dynamic linker state?), not the alignment for a C `main()`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh indeed! For OP, note that it's a very bad idea to call any libc functions from a program that didn't initialize the C runtime environment by being linked through the C compiler. Don't do that!

Comment: More like you have to init libc in a static binary. `gcc -static -nostartfiles foo.o` will still link libc, but start at your entry point instead of CRT.  On Linux, `gcc -nostartfiles foo.o` will make a dynamic executable, and libc startup functions will be called by the dynamic linker before you reach `_start` (because it has a list of function pointers in a `.init` section or something).  @SergeyPetunin, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain/36901649 for stuff about linking with/without libc and static vs. dynamic.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, I've replaced `_main` with default entry point `start` (without the underscore, though — not sure if it's an OS X thing), but that didn't change much. Running through lldb, I found that in any way the execution starts with some boilerplate code which calls something like `dyldbootstrap::start`, and libc seems to be dynamically loaded and initialized correctly (at least `_printf` is working as expected). But the stack is still misaligned upon entering my code and has to be corrected manually.