# Moving a number to a stack variable does not work

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, att

I have a problem working on stacks.

Say for example I am in a stack and I already used movl %esp, %ebp

If I make 2 local word-sized variables (subl $4, esp), whenever I go to movw $1, -2(%ebp) it triggers a segmentation fault. Why is that so? Also, are immediate values allowed to be passed directly to stack variables?

My code is:

```
    movw $12, %ax 
    pushw %ax 
    call _function 
exit: 
    movl $1, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80

_function: 
    movl %esp, %ebp 
    subl $4, %esp 
    movw $2, -2(%ebp) 
    addl $4, %esp 
    ret $2
```

I assemble, link and run with:

```
as myfile.s -o myfile.o
ld myfile.o 
./a.out
```

I'm on a 64-bit system.

Comment: You assembling as 32-bit or 64-bit code? Yes, you can move an immediate to any memory operand. I also assume you mean `subl $4, %esp`. Are you actually sure it crashes right on `movw $1, -2(%ebp)`? Did you see this in the debugger?

Comment: If you showed us a minimal complete verifiable example we could probably tell you what has gone wrong.

Comment: This is 32-bit assembly code.

Comment: Can you show us all your code and how you assemble and link it? And I'd like to see the output of this command `file ./myexec` where `myexec` is the name of your executable.

Comment: You're probably building it as 64-bit, like Michael suggested: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain.  That would explain what you're seeing.

Comment: movw $12, %ax
pushw %ax
call _function

exit:
movl $1, %eax
movl$0, %ebx
int $0x80

_function:
movl %esp, %ebp
subl $4, %esp
movw $2, -2(%ebp)
addl $4, %esp
ret $2

Comment: as myfile.s -o myfile.o
ld myfile.o
./a.out

Comment: file ./a.out returned a message like: ELF 64-bit executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not strippped

Comment: If you are on a 64-bit system `as myfile.s -o myfile.o` followed by `ld myfile.o` will create a 64- bit executable. If you are on 64-bit Linux and want to create a 32-bit executable you'll want to use `as --32 myfile.s -o myfile.o` and  `ld -melf_i386 myfile.o`

Comment: The file output tells me you built a 64-bit executable (also gathered that by the commands you used to assemble and link).

Comment: It worked. Thanks!