# How to change the start/main entrypoint of x86-64 assembly with NASM?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, nasm

I have this:

```
$ make build
read.o: In function `_start':
read.asm:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

From this asm:

```
global main

section   .text
main:   mov       rax, 1                  ; system call for write
          mov       rdi, 1                  ; file handle 1 is stdout
          mov       rsi, message            ; address of string to output
          mov       rdx, 13                 ; number of bytes
          syscall                           ; invoke operating system to do the write
          mov       rax, 60                 ; system call for exit
          xor       rdi, rdi                ; exit code 0
          syscall                           ; invoke operating system to exit

section   .data
message:  db        "Hello, World", 10      ; note the newline at the end
```

I am running it with this:

```
$ nasm -felf64 read.asm -o read.o && gcc read.o -o store && ./store
```

How do I change the word `main` to something other than `main` or `_start`, such as `begin` or `myentrypoint`? I would like to customize it. Can it even be customized?

Comment: Your asm defines a `main`, not a `_start`, so this `gcc read.o` is the right command to link it with CRT start files that call `main`.  Did your intended [mcve] use `_start:` instead of `main:`, for you to build into a static executable with `gcc -static -nostdlib read.o`?  Or simply `ld read.o -o store`.  I have an `asm-link` wrapper script that assembles + links a single file into an executable, included in my answer on [Assembling 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit system (GNU toolchain)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36861903)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `main` is not the entrypoint.  The entrypoint is `_start` provided by `crt0.o` which eventually calls `main`.  You cannot change that.  However, you can provide your own startup code that calls some other function than `main`.

Note that the entrypoint itself can be set to whatever symbol you like with the `-e` option to `ld`.  Refer to the manual for details.  Note however that if you change this, the C runtime code will no longer work correctly.  Use only with your own runtime code.

One option to change `main` to something else is setting `main` to be an alias for some other symbol, e.g. with

```
.set main, mymain
```

in some assembly file.  Alternatively, simply provide a dummy `main` function that jumps to your actual main function:

```
        global  main
main:   jmp     mymain
```

Comment: So what should the final command sequence and assembly look like?

Comment: @LancePollard I don't know because I am not sure what exactly you want.  You talk about `main` in one place, “entrypoint” in the other and then provide an error message I cannot reproduce.  If you can narrow it down to an exact description of what you want, then I can produce such a command sequence for you.

Comment: Note that `.set main, mymain` is GAS syntax, not NASM.  I'm not sure if NASM supports generating weak aliases for symbols.

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed, there doesn't seem to be any support for this.  The trampoline approach will work however.