# Why doesn't `ld -L -l...` match the behavior of `ld /path/to/library.so`?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, ld, musl

I have two questions highlighted below. I'm using 64-bit Linux.

I saw on another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36901649/1509433) that `MUSL` was mentioned as a `libc` implementation.

I tried using this with the following *Hello world* assembly program that uses two `libc` functions, `write` and `_exit`.

```
  .data
hello:
  .ascii "Hello, world\n"

  .text
  .globl _start
_start:
  movl $13, %edx
  movl $hello, %esi
  movl $1, %edi
  call write

  movl $0, %edi
  call _exit
```

I assembled the code with:

```
# Command 1
$ as -o hello.o hello.s
```

I then ran `ld` to generate an executable that statically links `MUSL` `libc`.

```
# Command 2
$ ld hello.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl/libc.a
```

That generated an `a.out` file that works as expected, outputting "Hello, world" when executed.

I also tried a different invocation of the preceding `ld` command, using `-static -lc` instead of specifying the path directly, and also using `-L` to give the path to `MUSL` so that `glibc` is not used, since the latter is already on `ld`'s search path.

```
# Command 3
$ ld hello.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl/ -static -lc
```

That worked as expected.

Next I tried to dynamically link `MUSL` `libc`.

```
# Command 4
$ ld -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 hello.o \
     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl/libc.so
```

That appears to work as expected. I can run `a.out`, and calling `ldd` on `a.out` shows that `MUSL`'s `libc` is linked.

Lastly, I tried an analogous modification relative to the statically linked version earlier, using `-lc` and `-L` instead of specifying the path to the `.so` file directly.

```
# Command 5
$ ld -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 hello.o \
     -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl -lc
```

The program does not run properly, outputting the error:

```
bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory
```

When I run that same `ld` command with the `--verbose` flag, the output is the same as when passing `--verbose` to the earlier `ld` command (`Command 4` that generated a working executable).

Running `ldd` on `a.out` also outputs an error:

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so: invalid ELF header
```

**Question 1: Why does calling `ld` with `-L` and `-lc` in this case not match the behavior from earlier, where I specified the `.so` file directly?**

I noticed that if I change the specified dynamic linker to `/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1`, the generated `a.out` runs as expected.

```
# Command 6
$ ld -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 hello.o \
     -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl -lc
```

However, calling `ldd` on the generated `a.out` produces the following error, which was not the case earlier when I did not use `-lc` and `-L` in `Command 4`:

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so: invalid ELF header
```

**Question 2: Why does `ld` fail on this binary, but worked earlier when I passed the path of the `.so` file to `ldd` and used a different dynamic linker?**

Comment: At the very least re-run the above commands with `--verbose` to see what actually happened.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm., I tried running the commands with the `--verbose`, which outputs the internal linker script that's used, followed by `ld: mode elf_x86_64`, `attempt to open hello.o succeeded`, `hello.o`, `attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl/libc.so succeeded`, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl/libc.so`. The `--verbose` output is the same for both commands 4 and 5 above, which I've updated the post to indicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I encountered was due to using `-L` with the linker, but not having that path available for loading `libc.so` at runtime.

I noticed this by calling `readelf --dynamic --program-headers` on the programs generated by `Command 4` and `Command 5`.

```
 # Command 4
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl/libc.so]
 # Command 5
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libc.so]
```

I was able to resolve the issue for the program generated by `Command 5` by using an environment variable, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl`, when running the program, or alternatively by passing an extra argument to `ld`, `-rpath /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl`.