# Assembling x86 assembly source code on x86_x64 architecture

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I'm reading a book on how to write assembly for x86 Linux.

I want to assemble the following assembly source code (exit.s) on my x86_x64 Linux OS:

```
.section .data

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    mov1 $1, %eax
    mov1 $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

By calling this command: `as exit.s -o exit.o`

However, the assembler exits with the following error:

```
exit.s: Assembler messages:
exit.s: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
exit.s:6: Error: no such instruction: `mov1 $1,%eax'
exit.s:7: Error: no such instruction: `mov1 $0,%ebx'
```

From what I can gather, the instruction set for x86_x64 Linux is different from x86, hence the error. By replacing `mov1` with `mov`, the assembler succeeds in compiling. However, seeing as the rest of the book is written for x86, I would like to be able to assemble x86 assembly for my OS.

I read somewhere that it's possible to do so by specifying the option `--32`, like so: `as --32 exit.s -o exit.o`, but by doing that, I receive the same error as before.

How do I assemble x86 source code on an x86_x64 architecture?

Comment: `mov1` is not valid even for correct 32-bit x86 assembly. You probably want `movl` (last character is an `L`). But that does not solve your question, to use the int 80h API you do want to compile into a 32-bit application.

Comment: Try the `gcc` commands given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain/36901649#36901649

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I mistook the l for a 1. Using the gcc compiler worked.

Comment: By the way, as that answer lists: "Use `-v` to have gcc show you the commands it runs to assemble and link."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with this code:

```
 mov1 $0, %ebx
```

It should be `movl`, (See the difference between `1` and `l`, in some fonts they are the same.)

The other, a minor one is the missing newline, simply insert one at the end of the file.

To assemble the file use `as --32 exit.s -o exit.o` (Assuming a 64-bit assembler)

Comment: I already tried the command you suggest. I'm not sure whether or not it fails because my assembler is not 64-bit (I run x86_x64). Is there any way to check whether or not my assembler is 64-bit? I had to use gcc to compile it to a 32-bit binary can my os could execute.

Comment: @MikeHawkins What error message did you get with `as --32`?  This should work just fine after you fix the `mov1` error.

Comment: My comment was not correct - what I meant was, the assembler succeeds, but the linker fails with the following message: `ld: i386 architecture of input file `exit.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output`

Comment: Does this work? `ld -m elf_i386 -o executable file.o` Has `ld` support for 32-bit output?