# Assembly with VIM - Automatic tabs + doing both commands at the same time

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, vim, nasm, ld

I am new to NASM especially in ubuntu64 using vim.

Currently, when I write assembly code with vim, it does not recognize the labels and does not auto-tab, maybe it's because it's not supposed to do that (it's not conventional) although I would be pretty happy if it could do that here too.. (like auto tab with python on vim)

[Vim assembly code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPc2g.png)

When I press enter it goes back to the beginning of the line, where the red arrow points.

Secondly, when I need to "compile" (I don't know if it's the right term here, maybe "assemble") the code, I need to write both:

```
nasm -f elf64 hello.asm
```

and

```
ld -s -o hello hello.o
```

Is there a shorter way of doing so? maybe both at the same time, an easy 2-in-1 command?

Comment: Can you simply put both on one line as a compound command like `nasm ... && ld ...`?  If Vim uses a shell to run commands, the shell will parse the &&

Answer (score 1):

Create a shell script:  make a new text file and name it "assemble.sh" or whatever you want, then type in the following two lines.

```
nasm -f elf64 "$1.asm"  &&
 ld -o "$1" "$1.o"              # only try ld if assembling succeeded
```

You might want to add other options to get NASM to add more or less debugging info, depending on how you debug.  `ld -s` would strip the binary, but you generally don't want that for debugging.

Then you have to make it executable with a "`chmod +x assemble.sh`"

so then you can `./assemble.sh hello`.  Or put it in your ~/bin directory you it's in your PATH.

Comment: I have a script called `asm-link` that does basically that, supporting a few options like `-m32`, and `-d` to disassemble the output.  It takes `foo.asm` as an input so tab-completion fully works, and strips the suffix to find the base name.  It's part of my answer on [Assembling 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit system (GNU toolchain)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36901649) but probably it would be a better fit here on this new Q&A.