# Where does SASM store output binary?

Tags: assembly, sasm

I've read the git's repository of SASM and the internet and can find any information on where SASM stores the binary output. I have built a simple assembly file with NASM for x64 and after it gets built. I have searched for it using "find / programfile" and it keeps saying 'programfile: No such file or directory. I just am starting to learn assembly and installed SASM on Linux Mint. I've wanted to try out SASM since it has a debugger. If I build it with make the binary gets created. Anyone can help me understand why SASM does not produce the binary?

Comment: `find / programfile` is telling find to recursively list two paths, `/` and `programfile`.  But the second one doesn't exist in the current directory.  I think you meant to run `find `/ -name programfile` to search for that filename on your whole system.  (Probably be faster to start looking in just your homedirectory, `find ~ -name programfile`)

Comment: I'd guess it would produce it in the same directory as the source `.asm`, or in the directory you started SASM from.

Comment: still no go. SASM acts the same way on Windows too. Some reason it does not produce the binary. Atleast so I can run it outside of SASM. I guess I will just stick with using make files. What a peice of ???! Thanks anyways

Comment: I've never used SASM (just emacs or vim depending on mood, plus a command line with a one-liner or [script to assemble+link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain/36901649#36901649)), but I'd be surprised if it doesn't produce an executable somewhere.  If it lets you run the program, you could write a program that reads terminal input or sleeps, then use another terminal to find the PID of the running process.  `ls -l /proc/<PID>/exe` will show you where it's running from.

Comment: Thanks guys finally at a point in the tutorial book I am reading said to save the executable, You have to click the "Save .exe" menu item under the file menu item LOL! I can't beleive still it cant be done during the build phase.. Thanks all who have replied! atleast I figured it out HAHA! :)

Answer (score 1):

On Linux it writes the files to /tmp/SASM/. Intermediary and executables.