# Why this ASM-code demo throw segmentation fault in x86/64-Linux machine？

Tags: linux, assembly

Now the code is here:

```
.code32
#PURPOSE - Given a number, this program computes the
# factorial. For example, the factorial of
# 3 is 3 * 2 * 1, or 6. The factorial of
# 4 is 4 * 3 * 2 * 1, or 24, and so on.
#
.section .data
#This program has no global data
.section .text
.globl _start
.globl factorial #this is unneeded unless we want to share
_start:
pushl $4 
call factorial
addl $4, %esp
#the stack
movl %eax, %ebx 
#status

movl $1, %eax
int $0x80

.type factorial,@function
factorial:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp 
movl 8(%ebp), %eax

cmpl $1, %eax 
je end_factorial
decl %eax 
pushl %eax 
call factorial 
movl 8(%ebp), %ebx 
imull %ebx, %eax
end_factorial:
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp 
ret
```

This code is in *Programming from the Ground Up*
I need help to run this code right in WSL2.
Well,as the Title,why this ASM-code  demo throw segmentation fault in x86/64-Linux machine?
I'm new in ASM-code. Thanks from China.

Comment: It works correctly for me on Ubuntu 22.04, and returns exit code 24.  How are you building the program?  I used `gcc -m32 -nostdlib -o fac fac.s`.  I wonder if you have the wrong build options and are making a 64-bit executable by mistake.

Comment: Last time I checked, WSL does not support 32 bit code.  That may have changed though.

Comment: @fuz, WSL doesn't support running 32-bit, WSL2 does.

Comment: OP, do not supply a `.code32` directive!  This directive is not needed for correct code and masks you incorrect build flags.

Answer (score 3):

In your assembly code when you call `factorial` you pass the argument using the stack with `pushl $4`. That is 32-bit assembly and needs to be linked as a 32-bit executable.  In 64-bit the parameters are passed in registers, which would be `%rdi` in this case (first parameter).

A 64-bit x86 cpu can run 32-bit code but the binary needs to flag that. Compile your code with `gcc -m32 test.s -nostdlib -o test` then debug it with gdb:

```
gdb ./test.1
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.2
...
Reading symbols from ./test.1...
(No debugging symbols found in ./test.1)
(gdb) b _start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1000
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/test.1 

Breakpoint 1, 0x56556000 in _start ()
(gdb) set disassemble-next-line on
(gdb) si
0x56556014 in factorial ()
=> 0x56556014 <factorial+1>:    89 e5   mov    %esp,%ebp
(gdb) 
0x56556016 in factorial ()
=> 0x56556016 <factorial+3>:    8b 45 08        mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
(gdb) 
0x56556019 in factorial ()
=> 0x56556019 <factorial+6>:    83 f8 01        cmp    $0x1,%eax
(gdb) 
0x5655601c in factorial ()
=> 0x5655601c <factorial+9>:    74 0d   je     0x5655602b <end_factorial>
(gdb)
```

Comment: The code won't assemble in 64 bit mode anyway; `pushl %ebp` is not a valid instruction in 64 bit mode.

Comment: @fuz  Aha unfortunately it will. At least on Ubuntu 20.04/gcc 9.4

Comment: Ah, I totally missed the `.code32` directive.  Seems like OP found that it won't assemble and so slapped this directive on, “fixing” the assembly.  But now what he really has is 32 bit code in a 64 bit binary which won't work at all.  Folks, the `.code32` directive will not solve your problems!  Do not use it unless you know exactly what you are doing!

Comment: If the program had any static data (in `.data` or `.bss`), you'd also want to use `-static` or `-no-pie` on distros where the GCC default is `-pie`.  `mov $foo, %eax` needs an absolute address in the machine code, but a PIE executable doesn't know the right absolute address until it runs.  In a dynamically-linked PIE (not static-pie), the dynamic linker can apply those runtime fixups, but it's probably easier to debug and compare with objdump output if absolute addresses simpler, not 0x5655...  And GDB's `starti` to stop before the first user-space insn will be in ld.so, not your `_start`.

Comment: Also, your answer should mention that `.code32` is not helpful, and is only useful if you want to put 32-bit machine code in a 64-bit `.o`, e.g. if you're making a kernel that changes modes.  [Assembling 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit system (GNU toolchain)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36861903) is a duplicate of this which points that out.