# Segmentation fault when moving data to register

Tags: c, assembly

I'm trying to write a function that adds two numbers in assembly, and calling it through C. I am getting a segmentation fault when i `mov eax, [ebp+8]`. I know this because GDB says:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
add () at add_two_numbers.s:12
12          mov eax, [ebp+8]
```

Here is my Assembly code:

```
    .code32
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .global add

    .section .text
add:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    sub esp, 4

    mov eax, [ebp+8]
    add eax, [ebp+12]

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

and my C Driver code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int, int);

int main(void)
{
    int x = 4, y = 10;
    int z = add(x, y);
    printf("%d", z);

    return 0;
}
```

I Compile my code using `gcc -Wall -o main driver.c add_two_numbers.s`

Comment: Can you verify your compiled file is a 32 bit executable not a 64 bit executable?

Comment: @Joshua My file is 64 bit

Comment: Note for the future: The `.code32` directive is almost always wrong.  Its use has masked errors you would have gotten for your wrong toolchain configuration.  Do not use this directive unless you have a very good reason to.  If configured correctly, the assembler should emit code for the right mode from the beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading the manual I am now really certain of my answer.

The problem is on a modern Linux, the default output of `gcc` is a 64 bit binary. While `.code32` tells the assembler to create 32 bit code, it doesn't change the output file format to mark it as a 32 bit `.o` finally so you don't actually get the link error you would want.

32 and 64 bit code are close enough that particular code decoded correctly; but it can't possibly work. The problem is `rsp` is much higher than the 4GB barrier so `mov ebp, esp` didn't put the top of the stack into it, but a sheared-off pointer that points into nilspace.

The straightforward fix is to just go ahead and write 64 bit assembly.

```
    .code
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .global add

    .section .text
add:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    sub rsp, 16  # the stack frames are 16 byte aligned so if you're going to reserve stack space, do it right!

    # Arguments are in registers rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9
    mov eax, edi
    add eax, esi

    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

Comment: And what if I want to make it a 32 bit executable?

Comment: @IshaanDabhade: You get a 32 bit build chain and invoke it. Some platforms have `-m32` work but I'm used to that not working on x64, and it definitely won't work out of the box because you don't have the libraries requried. Long answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352783/how-can-i-build-and-run-32-bit-software-on-64-bit-debian

Comment: @IshaanDabhade: [Assembling 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit system (GNU toolchain)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36861903)

Comment: @PeterCordes: I found that question and concluded it's a bad duplicate because it's trying to build a self contained 32 bit binary with no C libraries. This one is trying to call printf.

Comment: Note that `gcc -g -m32 -no-pie` will probably not work for OP out of the box because the default state is no 32 bit libraries.

Comment: @Joshua: My answer to it also covers the case of `gcc -m32` without `-static -nostdlib`, for programs like this that only define a `main`, not `_start` and do want to link libc.  My answer also mentions the need to install a distro package like `gcc-multilib` if you don't have it.  But my answer is kind of cluttered and messy as a result, unfortunately.

Comment: There might be a better duplicate somewhere that's more focused on linking C and asm, rather than a whole small program written in asm.  The Q&A I linked is the first one I thought of to go looking for, and while it wasn't ideal, I decided it was sufficiently close to close as a duplicate.  The conceptual part, that `.code32` just lets you put 32-bit machine code in a 64-bit executable, is definitely applicable, and it has commands that will work to build this.